Resize CSS triangle with window size
I have a div <div class="arrow-up"> that defines a triangle using CSS.
Here's an example :


.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
<div class="arrow-down"></div>



I'm trying to make the triangle size responsive when the window is resized. I tried changing the boder from px to vh but it didn't change anything.

Using vh works for me when I change the viewport height.  Are you looking to respond to the viewport width with vw instead?  Maybe you want to use rem units?  It's not entirely clear to me what isn't working.

Do you want it to change width when the viewport changes width and height when the viewport changes height or do you want it to keep the same aspect-ratio? If so, what do you want to be the thing(s) that influence its dimensions?

stop using obsolete methods to draw triangles: https://css-generators.com/triangle-shapes/

@TemaniAfif There's nothing wrong with this method.



     .arrow-down {
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border-left: 5vw solid transparent;
          border-right: 5vw solid transparent;
          border-top: 5vh solid #f00;
        }
<div class="arrow-down"></div>




Interesting, but we don't know whether the OP wants to change the aspect ratio of the arrow or not - they need to define what they mean by 'responsive' in this case as it could be several things.

You are probably looking for the clamp() function:


.arrow-down {
  --size: clamp(4px, 3vmin, 20px);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: var(--size) solid transparent;
  border-right: var(--size) solid transparent;
  border-top: var(--size) solid #f00;
}
<div class="arrow-down"></div>



